# Not able to get my header and main to style correctly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a webpage that I am trying to do two things: in "desktop" view, I want the header to be on the side and in "mobile" view I want the header to be on the top. I also want the header to be fixed (or sticky) in place and I want there to be no "blank space" around the header either on the top or the side. My issue is if I do position sticky, I can't figure out how to get the header to take up the full width of the page (when at the top) or be oriented up and down at full height when in desktop view. But when I change position to fixed instead of sticky, the header covers much of the article while in mobile view and when I apply a margin-top value, it works (looks good) for that specific viewport, but with any resize of the browser window there is either too much or too little margin. 
TL;DR-
How do I keep the header fixed at the top (and the side) without covering content while also having the header have no white space surrounding the header?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora');
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FAEBD7;
}
    body > div {
        padding: .4em;
    }
header {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #6495ED;
    padding: 2.5%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FAEBD7;
}
    a:visited {
        color: #FAEBD7;
    }
nav {
    text-align: right;
}
nav li {
    list-style: none;
}
nav a {
    color: #FAEBD7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    nav a:visited {
        color: #FAEBD7;
    }
    nav a:active {
        color: #DEB887;
    }
    nav a:hover {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
article {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    margin: 2.5%;
    padding: 1%;
}
article figure {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10%;
}
    article a {
        color: #6495ED;
    }
        article a:visited {
            color: #6495ED;
        }
        article a:active {
            color: #DEB887;
        }
        article a:hover {
            color: black;
        }
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}
.post-date {
    color: grey;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 880px) {
    body > div {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 75em;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    article {
        width: 55%;
    }
    main {
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    img {
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kids Read for Fun | Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <header>
            <h1><a href="#">Kids Read for Fun</a></h1>
            <hr>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Current Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <article>
                <div class="post-date">January 6, 2016</div>
                <section class="post-content">
                <h2><a href="#">Septimus Heap Book One: Magyk</a></h2>
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSefEemDZe2rlGwqBTPEtZHr1pn54ve_q0eumcdUWQXvsEHd-D9" alt="Book cover for Septimus Heap 1">
                </figure>
                <p>If you enjoy stories about seventh sons of seventh sons and magyk this is the book for you. <a href="#">Read More...</a></p>
                </section>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div class="post-date">Dec 20, 2015</div>
                <section class="post-content">
                <h2><a href="#">Magnus Chase Book One: Sword of Summer</a></h2>
                <figure>
                    <img src="https://books.google.com/books/content/images/frontcover/xWuyBAAAQBAJ?fife=w300" alt="Book cover for Magnus Chase 1">
                </figure>
                <p>The anticipated new novel by Rick Riordan. After Greek mythology (Percy Jackson), Greek/Roman (Heroes of Olympus), and Egyptian (Kane Chronicles), Rick decides to try his hand with Norse Mythology, and the end result is good. <a href="#">Read More...</a></p>
                </section>
            </article>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSS grid and media queries for this. All of the problems are facing can be solved with grid-area.

Comment: As I posted it, I kept messing with it some more and was able to come to a solution that included css grid and some fixed solutions! Thanks